Azure application gateway Whenever we want to do any maintenance in our application we want our visitors to see the maintenance page
Whenever we want to do any maintenance in our application we want our visitors to see the maintenance page instead of the actual error. There should be a mechanism (script) to turn this on and off when maintenance starts and over.
For the maintenance we have 3 scenarios and we need 3 path based rules so that we can redirect our users to the maintenance page depending on that scenario. And we can turn this on and off by the script instead of manually from the portal.
How to do it ?
In Azure application gateway how to create the maintenance page by using the rewrite options

This might help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error

First, create a maintenance page (it can be a static HTML file) that you want to display to users during maintenance. Then, upload it to a hosting location (such as Azure Blob Storage). Once you have done this, configure rewrite rules in Azure Application Gateway that point to the maintenance page URL.

We are facing the difficulties to configure the rewrite rules for container app

What kind of difficulties? Can you specify?
